# Ethereum wallet backup doesn't produce any files

Tags: accounts, backup

I'm using ethereum wallet on windows 10. I have one account and I'm attempting to produce a backup of it. I do `Accounts > Backup > Accounts` and the file browser comes up, showing a directory with a geth directory and a keystore directory. The keystore directory is empty. So, where is the backup file?

Answer (score 0):

The backup action is only supposed to bring up the browser and show you the keystore directory where you should have one or multiple .json files (for manual backup) if you have created accounts. So that behavior is expected.

Why the keystore is empty I cannot answer, that is unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the reps needed to comment, apologies for this as I wanted to ask whether the user asking the question is using testnet, before venturing to answer.

In case, you are using testnet the keystore will be under `testnet > keystore` folder. The `accounts > backup > accounts` basically shows you the keystore you need to back up somewhere (maybe on drive or written somewhere). 
Similar is the case with application data.